# Looking for a proof that $\sqrt2 + \sqrt5 + \sqrt[3]3$ is irrational

Tags: nt.number-theory, irrational-numbers

What is the easiest way to prove that $\sqrt2+\sqrt5+\sqrt[3]3$ is irrational?

Comment: If it were rational, then $\sqrt[3]3$ would lie in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt5)$, which has degree $4$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: The map $\sqrt{2}\to -\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5}\to \sqrt{5}, \sqrt[3]{3}\to \sqrt[3]{3}$ extends to an automorphism of the field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5}, \sqrt[3]{3})$ but does not fix the sum.

Comment: The absolute Galois group $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ acts on this number, for example sending it to the number $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt[3]{3} \exp(2\pi i/3)$, which is not real. Since the absolute Galois group does not fix this number, it is irrational.

Comment: There are no non-trivial dependencies between radicals. See: Besicovitch A. S., On the linear independence of fractional powers of integers // J. London Math. Soc. 15 (1940), 3–6. A short proof: if such a dependence exists, dividing by one of radicals we get 1=sum(radicals), but the trace of each radical equals 0 while the trace of 1 is not 0.

Comment: @dodd why does it extend? It does not seem obvious for me.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao what is the automorphism which acts this way?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: It is a basic field theory.

Comment: To the original poster: I hope LSpice's comment is clear to you. If not, this question might fair better at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DavidESpeyer where does $\sqrt[3]{3}$ map to $-\sqrt[3]{3}$? dodd's automorphism exists, I think, but a simple reason why is not still clear for me.

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I misread dodd's comment. (And I have now deleted my wrong one.) Okay, dodd's comment is right, though it is not the hint I would have given.